# CMake build .sln file

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm currently trying to get a bit of knowledge about CMake and how to build projects etc. I'm following tutorial on this site:
https://hsf-training.github.io/hsf-training-cmake-webpage/02-building/index.html

And quite early I've reached a problem that I don't understand. So basicly I've tried those "newer" methods of building:

```
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build
```

It went smoothly and without any problems. But as I'm more familiar with usage of **cmake-gui** and then using simple **make** or **ninja** build generator I wanted to try that and compare with those previous lines. Moreover author himself wrote alternative syntax which is simply:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

And that caused a lot of problems... After I tried **make** command I've got an error:

```
Fatal: Unable to open makefile
```

After that I tried **cmake-gui**. I specified **Ninja** as project generator, and after generating is done I tried to execute **ninja** command. Than I've got this error:

```
C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 - BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build>ninja
[0/2] Re-checking globbed directories...
[1/97] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/OptionalTest.dir/OptionalTest.cpp.obj
FAILED:
tests/CMakeFiles/OptionalTest.dir/OptionalTest.cpp.obj D:\minGW\bin\c++.exe   -I../include -I../tests -Itests -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wswitch-enum -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -MD -MT tests/CMakeFiles/OptionalTest.dir/OptionalTest.cpp.obj -MF tests\CMakeFiles\OptionalTest.dir\OptionalTest.cpp.obj.d -o tests/CMakeFiles/OptionalTest.dir/OptionalTest.cpp.obj -c ../tests/OptionalTest.cpp
In file included from ../tests/OptionalTest.cpp:12: ../tests/app_helper.hpp: In function 'void put_env(std::string, std::string)':
../tests/app_helper.hpp:55:5: error: '_putenv_s' was not declared in this scope; did you mean '_wputenv'?
    55 |      _putenv_s(name.c_str(), value.c_str());
       |     ^~~~~~~~~
       |     _wputenv
```

Then I tried **cmake-gui** again but with **MinGw Makefiles** generator, and I received error:

```
Error makefile 11: Colon expected
```

Lastly I returned to `cmake ..` command and find out that it returns `.sln` Visual Studio type of **build pipeline**. So I've searched for command to build `.sln` project from Command Line. I've tried this command:

```
msbuild SlnFolders.sln
```

And as I expected it was not working again, I've got this error:

```
C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 - BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build>msbuild CLI11.sln
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 18.08.2021
13:26:40. Project "C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 - BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build\CLI11.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 - BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build\CLI11.sln.metaproj : error MSB41 26: The specified solution configuration "Debug|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 -
 BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build\CLI11.sln]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tomasy\Desktop\programming\CMake tutorials\L1 - BuildingWithCMake\CLI11\build\CLI11.sln " (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

So... Can someone help me to understand what magic happens when i used that first method? Why only this "newer" method is working, and why any other are not?

And beside that last of these command :

```
cmake --build build --target test
```

is not working either. Anyone know why? I've got :

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: tests.vcxproj
```

Comment: When it gave you "Fatal: Unable to open makefile" have you looked at the makefile? Did it exist in the build directory?

Comment: @DoritoJohnson as I mentioned when i returned to **cmake..* syntax I found out that i've got **.sln** instead of **makefile**. Then I tried to build it with **msbuild SlnFolders.sln** command but it was not working.